# USA TST 2007, Problem 5 : Basic Geometry (Similar Triangles)

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I am given with a Triangle $ABC$ which is inscribed in circle $\omega$. The tangent lines to $\omega$ at $B$ and $C$ meet at $T$. Point $S$ lies on ray $BC$ such that $AS$ is perpendicular to $AT$. Points $B_1$ and $C_1$ lies on ray $ST$ (with $C_1$ in between $B_1$ and $S$) such that $B_{1}T=BT=C_{1}T$. I need to prove that the triangles $ABC$ and $AB_1C_1$ are similar to each other.

Comment: Maybe it means $B_1T=BN=C_1S$? Show please your attempts.

Comment: We have $B_1T=BT=CT=C_1T$. But $B,C$ are the only two points on the line $ST$ which are a distance $BT$ from $T$. So if $B_1,C_1$ are distinct then they must coincide with $B,C$. I think you have a typo somewhere in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rewritten version of the OP with a picture. The order of "inventing" the points (in the solution using inversion) is the same as the order of the "inverted" points in a lemma. The lemma is simple, extracts the essence and gives the bridge for the solution. (Writing the lemma is not so simple, points have to be constructed in the right order.)

> **Proposition**:
>   There are given two circles with centers $O$ and $T$, which intersect orthogonally in two points, $B$ and $C$. The two circles are denoted by $(O)$, $(T)$, using their centers, if there is no danger of confusion.
>
> Let $U=OT\cap BC$ be the mid point of the segment $BC$.
>
> Let $S$ be a point on the **ray** = half-line $BC$, so that the circle with diameter $ST$ intersects $(O)$ in two points, $A$ and $a$. Here $A$ is on the bigger arc $\overset\frown{BC}$.
>
> Let $B_1,C_1$ be the intersections of the **line** $ST$ with the circle $(T)$ , so that the points $B_1,T,C_1,S$ appear in this order on the line.
>
> [image: math stackexchange problem, dan_fulea, 3518232]
>
> **Then we have the following properties:**
>
> $(1)$ The points $B,T,C_1,A$ are on a circle.
>
> $(2)$ The points $B,T,B_1,a$ are on a circle.
>
> $(3)$ The points $A,B,B_1,S$ are on a circle.
>
> $(1')$ The points $C,T,B_1,A$ are on a circle.
>
> $(2')$ The points $C,T,C_1,a$ are on a circle.
>
> $(3')$ The points $A,C,C_1,S$ are on a circle.
>
> $(4)$ The triangles $\Delta ABB_1$, $\Delta ACC_1$ are similar.
>
> $(5)$ The triangles $\Delta ABC$, $\Delta AB_1C_1$ are similar.

---

Before we proceed, we consider the situation obtained by applying an inversion $X\to X'$ centered in $B$. Let $D$ be the intersection of $BT$ with the circle $(T)$, so that $BD$ is a diameter of $(T)$. By inversion, circles through $B$ are mapped into projective lines, so that $B\to B'=\infty$, and $\infty\to\infty'=B$. A line through $B$ is mapped in the same line. The inversion picture is then constructed using points from the following lemma.

---

> **Lemma:** Let $B$ be a point in the plane. Consider two perpendicular lines passing through $B$, and two points $A', T'$ on them respectively, so that we have
>   $$BA'\perp BT'\ .$$
>
> Let $D'$ be the mid point of segment $BT'$.
>
> The perpendiculars in $D'$ and $A'$ on the lines $BD'T'$ and respectively $BA'$ intersect in a point $C'$.
>
> Let $U'$ be the reflection of $B$ w.r.t. $C'$. (So $C'$ is the mid point of $BU'$.)
>
> The circle $(A'U'T')$ intersects the lines $A'C'$ in $a'$, so that $A'a'$ is the diameter of this circle.
>
> The line $A'T'$ intersects $C'D'$ in a point $B_1'$.
>
> We consider the heights in triangle $\Delta A'a'B_1'$, and let its orthocenter be $C_1'$. Let $S'\in B_1'A'$ be the foot of the height from $a'$, $a'S'\perp B_1'A'$.
>   and $BC'U'$ in $S'$.
>
> The circle $(BS'T')$ intersects $D'C'$ in two points, $B_1', C_1'$, chosen so that $C_1'$ is between $D'$ and $C'$.
>
> [image: math stackexchange, inversion solution, problem 3518232, dan_fulea]
>
> **Then we have:**
>
> - $C_1'$ is the intersection of the diagonals in the parallelogram $A'D'T'C'$, so it is the mid point of $D'C'$, and of $A'T'$.
> - The points $B, S', C_1', T', B_1'$ are on the circle.
> - The points $B,S',C',U'$ are colinear.

---

**Proof of the lemma:** Consider the four rectangles with a vertex in $C'$ which are congruent to the rectangle $A'C'D'B$, and the other vertices are among $A',B,D',T',U'$ or reflections of them w.r.t. $C'$.
We see that $A'C'$ goes through the mid point of $T'U'$. So $A'C'$ is the side bisector of $T'U'$ (in the isosceles triangle $\Delta A'T'U'$), this implies that $A'a'$ is a diameter in the circumcircle
$(A'S'T'a'U')$ of this triangle. So $A'T'\perp T'a'$.

By construction, $C_1'=A'T'\cap B_1'C'$ (intersection of two heights), so $C_1'=
D'C'\cap A'T'$ is the intersection of the diagonals in the parallelogram $A'C'T'D'$.

The triangles $\Delta B_1'C_1'T'$, $\Delta B_1'C_1'S'$ have both a right angle opposite to the side $B_1'C_1'$, so $B_1'C_1'$ is the diameter of the circle $B_1'T'C_1'S'$, and on this circle there is also $B$, the reflection of $T'$ w.r.t. the same diameter.

We need now to show that $B',S',C'$ are colinear. For this we compute the angle
$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{BS'C'}
&=
 \widehat{BS'B_1'}
+\widehat{B_1'S'C_1'}
+\widehat{C_1'S'C'}
\\
&=
 \widehat{BT'B_1'}
+90^\circ
+\widehat{C_1'A'C'}
\\
&=
 \widehat{A'a'T'}
+90^\circ
+\widehat{T'A'C'}
\\
&=
90^\circ
+90^\circ
=180^\circ\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This finishes the lemma.

$\square$

---

**Proof of the proposition:** Lines of colinearity containing points $X',Y',Z',\dots$ in the lemma correspond to circles through $B$ containing points inverted points $X,Y,Z$. So we have the claimed propositions 
$(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$; 
$(1')$, $(2')$, $(3')$. Let us use these circles to obtain equalities of angles.
We have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{ABS} &= \widehat{AB_1S} &&\text{ since $(ABB_1S)$ cyclic.}\\
\widehat{ACS} &= \widehat{AC_1S} &&\text{ since $(ACC_1S)$ cyclic. Passing to suplements:}\\
\widehat{ACB} &= \widehat{AC_1B_1}\ .
\\
\widehat{CAC_1} 
&= \widehat{CSC_1} &&\text{ since $(ACC_1S)$ cyclic,}\\
&= \widehat{BSB_1} \\
&= \widehat{BAB_1} &&\text{ since $(ABB_1S)$ cyclic. This implies}\\
\widehat{BAC} &= \widehat{B_1AC_1}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

$\square$

Answer (score 0):

Probably a different solution than the previous answer, hence sharing it!

**My Proof**: Beautiful problem indeed!

Since $T$ is the point of intersection of tangent at $B$ and $C$ wrt  $\omega$ , we get that $BT=CT$.

Now, using the conditions given us in the  problem, we get that $CT=B_{1}T=C_{1}T$.

Hence $BCC_1B_1$ is cyclic quad.

Now, define  $D$ as the midpoint of $BC$. Hence $TD\perp BC \implies TD \perp DS$ .

Since, $AS\perp AT$ ( given in the question ) , we get that $TDAS$ is cyclic.

Now, before proceeding further, we will state a lemma :

**Lemma**: Let $T$ be the intersection of the tangents to $(ABC)$ at $B$ and $C$ . Then line $AX$ is a symmedian , where a symmedian is the isogonal of a median in a triangle .

**Proof**: It can be directly proved  using sin law!

Hence, by the above lemma , we note that $AT$ is the $A-$symmedian  we have $\angle BAD=\angle TAC$.

[image]

Now, we are ready for angle chase!

Let $\angle BAD=\angle TAC= \theta$ , $\angle BAC= \alpha$ , $\angle ABC= B $ .

**Claim** : $ACC_1S$ is cyclic

**Proof** : Note that by tangent- side theorem , we get that $\alpha= \angle CBT= \angle BCT \implies \angle DTC= 90-\alpha$ .

Also, since $AS\perp AT$, we get that $\angle CAS= 90-\theta$ .

Also, since $TDAS$ is cyclic, we get $\angle DAT= \alpha -2\theta= \angle DST \implies \angle DTS = 90- (\alpha -2\theta) \implies \angle CTC_1=2\theta \implies \angle TC_1C=90-\theta \implies \angle CC_1S=90+\theta$ .

Hence we have $\angle CAS= 90-\theta$  and $\angle CC_1S=90+\theta$ . Hence $ACC_1S$ is cyclic.

**Claim**: $BB_1AS$ is cyclic

**Proof**: Note that $\angle BAS= 90+ \alpha - \theta \implies \angle ASB= 90-( B+\alpha - \theta) $.

By using the previous observation, that $\angle DST = \alpha -2\theta$ , we get that $\angle AST=\angle ASB_1= 90- (B+\theta)$ .

Again, using the previous observations that , $\angle BTC= 180-2\alpha$ and $\angle CTC_1=2\theta$ , we get that $ \angle BTB_1= 2 \alpha -2\theta \implies \angle B_1BT=90-(\alpha - \theta )$ .

Hence we get that $\angle B_1BA= 90+(B+\theta)$ .

Now since, $\angle ASB_1= 90- (B+\theta)$ and  $\angle B_1BA= 90+(B+\theta)$ , we get that  $BB_1AS$ is cyclic .

[image]

Now , the most beautiful part of this problem, spiral similarity !

Note that since $BB_1AS$ is cyclic and $ACC_1S$ is cyclic .Note that there is a spiral symmetry centered at $A$ dilating $\Delta ABC$ to $\Delta AB_1C_1$ .

Hence  $\Delta ABC \sim \Delta AB_1C_1$. And we are done!

[image]
Note: Can someone please verify? I am very new to spiral similarity ( I just learned it today ).

Thanks in advance.